# Make these click functions work without jQuery

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have created a vertical menu with sub menus. Each menu has min of 3 sub menus, and each sub menu only opens when the menu is clicked. (For this menu I need `jQuery` support) But, I don't use `jQuery` in any other pages SO I skipped linking `jQuery`. Without `jQuery` this is how it looks:without`jQuery`[image: my output]

**If coder can make work this without `jQuery` your welcome or how can i make this work with `CSS`

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/pLz0pdx8/2/) that works with `jQuery`
can some one make this work without `jQuery`

### Function

```
  $(function () {
      $('li ul').hide();
      $("#leftmenuidfrmslt li").click(function (e) {
          var submenu = $(this).children("ul");
          if (!$(submenu).is(":visible")) {
              $('li ul').slideUp("fast");
              submenu.slideDown("fast");
          } else {
              submenu.slideUp("fast");
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose a solution without jquery. You should add some classes to css and apply them to appropriate UL-tags in your html-code. here is a [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/bdp8jL74/) working on pure javascript (no jquery) Here the javascript source code is:

```
function getXmlHttp(){
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (ee) {
        }
    }
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
}
function hide(node){
    node.style.display='none';
}
function func(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var q = getXmlHttp();
    var url = this.getAttribute('href');
    q.open('GET', url , false);
    q.send(null);
    var result = 'File '+url+' not found.';
    if(q.status == 200) {
        result = q.responseText;
    }
    document.querySelector('.page').innerHTML = result;
    document.querySelector('#leftmenu').style.width = '70px';
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('li ul, #leftmenu b');
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        hide(items[i]);
    }
    this.removeEventListener('click',func(),false);
}

function slideUp(node){
    node.setAttribute('class', "submenu hidden");
}

function slideDown(node){
    node.setAttribute('class', "submenu visible");
}

function switchSubMenu(){
var ch = this.children;
    for(var i=0; i<ch.length; i++) {
        if (ch[i].nodeName == 'UL') {
            var v = document.getElementsByClassName("visible");
            if (v) {
                for(var j=0; j<v.length; j++){
                    if(v[j] != ch[i]) {
                        slideUp(v[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
          ch[i].getAttribute('class') == "submenu hidden" ? slideDown(ch[i]) : slideUp(ch[i]);
        }
    }
}

var sm = document.querySelectorAll('.submenu');
for(var i=0; i<sm.length; i++) {
    slideUp(sm[i]);
    sm[i].parentNode.addEventListener("click",switchSubMenu, false);
}
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal');
for(var j=0; j<links.length; j++) {
    links[j].addEventListener("click",func, false);
}
```

Comment: which things i should change

Comment: look at jsfiddle link for details.  add classes 'submenu', 'hidden' and 'visible'.

Comment: that's all i should change or anything else because i don't output like in fiddle

Comment: in css add classes: `.submenu {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
}
.hidden {
  max-height: 0;
}
.visible {
  max-height: 300px;
}
` and in html: change every `<ul>` which means submenu list to `<ul class="submenu">`. before `</body>` tag insert `<script>...</script>` with javascript code that I wrote earlier

Comment: am using onload function loading external page in same page when page is loaded the menu size will be reduce to `10% in width` but this does't works and the function is mentioned in question jsfiddle

Comment: didn't understand you.  You may try to change this selector: `#leftmenuidfrmslt li ul {
  left: 90%;
  position: relative;
  top: -46px;
}`
to make each submenu to be closer to it's main item

Comment: Oh. I see. trying to fix

Comment: @ i have error with these code can you create the same function in java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65781/discussion-between-banzay-and-sanoj-lawrence).

Answer (score 1):

Using attribute selectors, you can set the default `font-size` to `20px` and override for specific elements:

```
[class*="flaticon-"] {
    font-size: 20px;    
}

h4[class*="flaticon-"] {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

You should add the font size like this

```
.small-icon { 
    font-family:"Flaticon";
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
}
.small-icon:before {
    font-size: 20px;        
    margin-left: 0;
}
.big-icon { 
    font-family:"Flaticon";
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 1;
}
.big-icon:before {
    font-size: 40px;        
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

For the html

```
<div class="center boxborder">
    <ul class="social">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="small-icon flaticon-facebook12" style="color: #3399ff;"></span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"><span class="small-icon flaticon-social19" style="color:#33ccff;"></span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"><span class="small-icon flaticon-google109" style="color: #ff3300;"></span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="small-icon flaticon-linkedin11" style="color: #21a6d8;"></span></a>

        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, although you can technically do this in CSS, using jQuery or vanilla JS represents a better solution for a more capable setup.

It also ensures you maintain a correct and proper seperation of concerns between **content** (HTML), **styling** (CSS) and **functionality** (JS).

That said....you can get close in CSS using the below (or similar)

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yk6n12h/)

HTML

```
<div class='menuGroup'>
    <label id='item1'>
        <input type='radio' for='item1' name='menu1' />Item 1
        <div class='menuGroup'>
            <label id='subitem1'>
                <input type='radio' for='subitem1' name='submenu1' />Item 1
                <div class='menuGroup'>more menu levels...</div>
            </label>
            <label id='subitem2'>
                <input type='radio' for='subitem2' name='submenu1' />Item 2
                <div class='menuGroup'>more menu levels...</div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </label>
    <label id='item2'>
        <input type='radio' for='item2' name='menu1' />Item 2
        <div class='menuGroup'>
            <label id='subitem3'>
                <input type='radio' for='subitem4' name='submenu2' />Item 1
                <div class='menuGroup'>more menu levels...</div>
            </label>
            <label id='subitem4'>
                <input type='radio' for='subitem5' name='submenu2' />Item 2
                <div class='menuGroup'>more menu levels...</div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
label {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
label:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}
input {
    display:none;
}
input:checked+.menuGroup {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    left:100%;
    top:-1px;
}
label .menuGroup {
    display:none;
}
.menuGroup {
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```